# Write correct DataGridView cell backcolour

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, xmltextwriter

I have a `DataGridView` in which certain cells change color to red on click and back to white on click again. The problem I am having is that if I haven't clicked on a cell, the code thinks the cell's background color is `0` instead of `white`.

I am using an `XMLTextWriter` to `loop` through all the rows/columns in a `DataGridView` and write the cells background color to an XML file

This is the code I am using:

```
For Each tp As TabPage In Me.TabControl.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
                .  .  .
                For Each dgv As DataGridView In tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
                    .  .  .
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                        .   .   .
                        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                            If i = 1 Then
                                xw.WriteStartElement("task")
                                xw.WriteAttributeString("name", cell.Value)
                                **xw.WriteAttributeString("backcolour", cell.Style.BackColor.Name.ToString)**
                                xw.WriteEndElement()
                            Else
                                **xw.WriteElementString("cell", cell.Style.BackColor.Name.ToString) 'writes the background color of the cell**
                            End If
                            i = i + 1
                        Next cell
                        xw.WriteEndElement()
                        i = 1
                    Next row
                    xw.WriteEndElement()
                Next dgv
                xw.WriteEndElement()
            Next
```

Does anyone have any idea how to tell it to write `white` instead of `0`?

Please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: the correct spelling of `backcolour` is `backcolor`

Comment: @spajce sorry for the typo. Any ideas how to solve the issue? Thanks

Comment: try to check http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?523865-RESOLVED-XmlTextReader-amp-MemoryStream

Comment: @spajce sorry to be a pain but the proposed solution on that website doesn't solve my problem. The code still writes "0" instead of "white" to the XML file. This is driving me insane as I have been stuck on it for about 2 weeks now. Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you one more time for helping me

Comment: how about `cell.InheritedStyle.BackColor.ToArgb.ToString()`

Comment: @spajce I will try that later on and let you know if it works for me. Thank you one more time

Comment: @spajce I did it in a slightly different way. I managed to get it to write "Color[White]" and then just used regular expressions to get the part I need. Here is the code: (I had to upload it to PasteBin because SO doesn't display the syntax correctly): http://pastebin.com/jNAu1ndQ   Thank you for your help

Comment: I hope that can help someone in my situation. Sorry to have been a pain in the backside and thank you one more time for helping me.

Comment: its okay, I'm glad to help, yes right, why we here is to help with other developers/programmers like us. more power :)